# Continuity and Subspace Topology

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, examples-counterexamples

> [image]

I think the first one is false. If we let $(-1/2, 1/2) \subset \Bbb R$ and $(0,1/4) \subset \Bbb R$, then for $f(x) = x$ defined on $[0,1) \subset M = \Bbb R$, we have

$f^{-1}(-1/2, 1/2) = [0,1/2)$ and $f^{-1}(0,1/4) = (0,1/4)$ both are open in $[0,1)$, but not open in $M$.

I think the second one is right because it is open in the relative sense, and the modification would be (b) applied to (a).

Comment: For your example, i suppose you have $A=(-1/2,1/2)$ and $B=(0,1/4)$, so what is $[0,1)$?

Comment: @Pedro, no I have $A = B = [0,1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your counterexample doesn't make sense; the function $f(x) = x$ is certainly continuous at each point of $A \cup B = (-1/2, 1/2)$.

You are, however, correct that statement a) is false, but for a different reason. Consider $M = [0,1]$, and let $A = [0, 1/2)$ and $B = [1/2, 1]$. Then $A \cup B = M$.

What happens if we define $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$ to be constant (say, $f(x) = 0$), and on $B$ define $f(x) = 1$? Are these continuous? Is the resulting function on $A \cup B$ continuous?

Comment: so both statements are actually false...

Comment: The modification would be (I think this applies to both), make $f$ continuous relative to $A \cup B$. not just on $A$ and $B$ itself.